# What is the date function used to display month name from Date column in Teradata

Tags: teradata

I have a table with Date column and I need to display Month name.

I found EXTRACT(MONTH) function in teradata to display the month_number but it does not serve my purpose. I can still use case statement on month_number to display the month name.

Can someone help me with a better approach?

Comment: Mark the answer correct if the response below was correct.

Answer (score 2):

The full name is returned by `to_char(dateCol, 'Month')`

```
'Month' -> 'October'
'MONTH' -> 'OCTOBER'
'month' -> 'october'
'Mon' -> 'Oct'
'MON' -> 'OCT'
'mon' -> 'oct'
```